# The value of gravitational potential energy of a satellite in low-earth orbit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, virial-theorem

The gravitational potential energy of a satellite as it sits on earth is given by $$\frac{-GMm}{R}\tag 1$$ where $R$ is the earth's radius, $M$ is the earth's mass and $m$ is the satellite's mass.

If we take $R$ to be approximately equal since the orbit is low-earth, the total mechanical energy of that satellite in orbit is given by $$\frac{-GMm}{2R}\tag2$$

I don't understand the second calculation. If height is approximately the same, why is the second energy term 1/2 of the first?

Comment: What is your conceptual difficulty in this derivation?

Comment: If height is approximately the same, why is the second energy term 1/2 of the first?

Comment: I'm a bit surprised this was closed. It's asking about the virial theorem and that seems like a concept in physics to me.

Comment: Yes, the question is about the concept behind the solution.

Answer (score 2):

@Garf's answer arrived before I could finish my text. Therefore, I'll skip deriving the result for a circular orbit. I would like to add a couple of comments.

1. The final result is not confined to circular orbits. Provided that the energies are averaged over a period, it holds for every closed orbit, in the form of the total energy being $\frac12$ of the average potential energy. It is a consequence of the [viral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem) in Mechanics.
2. A key ingredient for the theorem is the $1/r$ dependence of the potential energy. The validity of this result for low-Earth orbits is questionable. Multipole deviations from the pure $1/r$ behavior are observable. At first approximation, the equatorial bulge introduces a sizable quadrupole term.

Comment: I think the answer you refer to has been removed. It would be awesome if you could provide the derivation. Thanks, anyways.

Comment: @SB_16 You should be able to see the reason this question has been closed. You should try to edit the question so that it is more focused on the underlying physics concepts. The reason Garf's answer was removed is precisely due to the fact that your question has been considered homework-like. I share John Rennie's point of view that this is a conceptual question, however, I cannot provide the derivation if the question is not re-opened.